# Appium: Cannot retrieve git revision for Appium version 1.9.1 from GitHub. Original error: Error: read ECONNRESET

Tags: appium, appium-android

I'm trying to run the Appium server through below code and getting the below error.

```
AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(new AppiumServiceBuilder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe"))
            .withAppiumJS(new File("Path of main.js"))
            .withIPAddress("0.0.0.0").usingPort(4723));
            service.start();
```

**Logs:**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2

[35m[Appium][39m Welcome to Appium v1.9.1

[35m[Appium][39m Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
[35m[HTTP][39m [37m-->[39m [37mGET[39m [37m/wd/hub/status[39m
[35m[HTTP][39m [90m{}[39m
[debug] [35m[GENERIC][39m Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[debug] [35m[GENERIC][39m Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.9.1"}}
[35m[HTTP][39m [37m<-- GET /wd/hub/status [39m[32m200[39m [90m10 ms - 67[39m
[35m[HTTP][39m [90m[39m
[35m[Appium][39m **Cannot retrieve git revision for Appium version 1.9.1 from GitHub. Original error: Error: read ECONNRESET**
```

Comment: I get the exact same error for v1.9.1, after I installed Appium 1.7.1 directly from site: https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.7.1 .  Why?